# How much time SKStoreReviewController will show Prompt on actual Device?

Tags: ios, ios11, skstorereviewcontroller

I can see the SKStoreReviewController app-Rating prompt everytime i call the Request function in my Xcode Simulator.But will i see it in the Device too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as it is a DEBUG build. When you ship your app, the dialog won’t be displayed always. This is clearly described [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview).

Comment: Thanks , i thought that it will prompt every time when called, thnx anyway